# Output being submitted numerous times

Tags: php

Currently I am using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to scrape a website [view here](http://screenrant.com/movie-news/) to see the website I am scraping, everything comes back fine except it continues to put the same content for every single post it scrapes.. [View here to see demo](http://news.wubstub.com/t/test.php)

```
$page = (isset($_GET['p'])&&$_GET['p']!=0) ? (int) $_GET['p'] : '';  
$html = file_get_html('http://screenrant.com/movie-news/'.$page);

foreach($html->find('#site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > section > ul > li > div.info > h2 > a') as $element)
{
    print '<br><br>';
    echo $url = ''.$element->href;
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    $image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
    $news['image'] = $image->content;
    #print '<br><br>';

    // Ending The Featured Image

    #site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > section > ul > li:nth-child(2)

    $title = $html2->find('#site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > header.single-header > h1',0);
    $news['title'] = $title->plaintext;

    // Ending the titles
    print '<br>';
    #site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > div
    $articles = $html2->find('#site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > div > p');
    foreach ($articles as $article) {
    #echo "$article->plaintext<p>"; 
    $news['content'] = $news['content'] . $article->plaintext . "<p>";
    }

    print '<pre>';print_r($news);print '</pre>';

    print '<br><br>';

        // mysqli_query($DB,"INSERT INTO `wp_scraped_news` SET
             //                   `hash` = '".$news['title']."',
               //                 `title` = '".$news['title']."',
                 //               `image` = '".$news['image']."',
                   //             `content` = '".$news['content']."'");
         // print '<pre>';print_r($news);print '</pre>';
}
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong here but I am assuming it's one of two things and I have messed around with both of these things with no luck.

**1. I am doing something wrong with how my `foreach` are laid out.**

**2. The website is changing selectors for each new article.**

In both cases I am probably wrong.. but I've tinkered with them both for about 2 hours now and at the point of giving up.. any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I think your select path may be wrong.  In Chrome, select the HTML element you want, right-click then click Copy > Copy selector.  I get something that looks like this: `#site-top > div.site-wrapper > div.top-content > article > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div.info > div > div > p` -- probably need to change this `li:nth-child(2)` to this `li` .. a place to start though.

Comment: @Clayton if you look at the code displayed, I have that commented out, because I've tried it already.. - Just put that code in again, and it returns only the snippets displayed on the **News** archive page, we're declaring the URL at the top which means we're able to scrape the content pages also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not clearing out the old content from `$news['content']`. So when you process the second page, you're appending its content to the content of the first page. And the third page appends to this again, and so on.

Put

```
$news['content'] = '';
```

before

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
```

Comment: Look at your output more carefully. It's not showing the same content for each post. The beginning is the same, but it gets longer each time.

Comment: I am for sure doing this incorrectly.. can you please edit your post to display exactly how I should have it? Because placing `$article['content'] = '';` above my `foreach ($articles as $article) {` just returns a error on line 43.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be `$news['content'] = '';`. That's the variable I said you need to clear out in the text.

Comment: Didn't you think it was strange that I said you need to clear out one variable, then my code said to clear a different variable? If you thought about it, it should have been obvious that I made a mistake.

Comment: Been awake for around 20+ hours, I am not reading into things very well any more.

Comment: Don't just blindly copy code, **understand** it. Otherwise you don't learn.